# Multiple subdomains connected to meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor

Many subdomains are forwarded to subdomain X where my meteor app is working.

I'm using code which doesn't work:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.connection.domain); // is null 
    console.log(req.server.domain); // is null
    next();
});
```

Trying also to use `IronRouter` on server:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('testRoute', {
        where: 'server',
        path: '*',

        action: function () {
            console.log(this.request.connection.domain);  // null
        }
    });
});
```

I know that `FastRender` injects headers and it works , but the question is :

**How can I get subdomain from which user accesses meteor app using WebApp.connectHandlers or IronRouter ?**

Comment: In the first example, try logging `req.headers` as well. One of the strings there should contain the original request domain. However, that might depend on how your proxy is configured. What do you use to forward those domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, log `req.headers` to console as well. One of the strings there should contain the original request domain. However, that might depend on how your proxy is configured.